# Arduino Ethernet Shield Web Server Force Refresh After Link Is Pressed

Tags: javascript, html, arduino

I have an Arduino Ethernet shield with an Arduino Mega 2650 running my home automation web server. The html files that the server runs from are retrieved from an SD card. It works in the way that when a link on the web page is clicked, it adds an appendix to the link (http://192.168.1.xxx/ goes to http://192.168.1.xxx/?turnsomethingon) and the Arduino uses a readString to detect the appendix added and performs an action based on what it is.

Once the link is clicked, I need to clear the appendix from the end of the link and refresh the page, so that if I refresh the page the Arduino does not trigger the same command again (this is important as some of the links on the page tell the Arduino to switch html files on the SD to display a different page). At the minute when you press the link you have to manually delete the appendix from the link in the search bar and then manually refresh the page to get the new web page up.

I cannot use the auto refresh meta command with a set time delay as there are tablets in the room constantly connected to the page and this would cause problems, and also having the page refresh every second in order to switch web pages quickly would be impractical and annoying.

If anyone needs to see specific sections of code to help, I can post them but for the minute I haven't as the sketches and HTML web pages are very long.

Many thanks in advance, this problem has been driving me mad for a while now.